# How to make fixed div inside a scrollable div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with 2 divs, actually I have a fixed div inside a scrollable div now I want to scroll inner div along with the other div but not on the document scrollbars I have pasted the working link here if you can do it with deve mode to change with CSS or if their is need of any jquery script kindly let me know it. the link to the page which is purely HTML you can check it on

http://www.speedyrecruiter.com/problemwithdiv.html

When you click on plus button a popup div open with fixed height width top left now I want this div to b scrollable along with inner div not with outer document.

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is more useful for futur people looking for the answer to the same question.

Comment: i have tried both positions fixed and absolute but i can't get the desired result with both i want to stick the div inside the inner scrollable div.

Answer (score 0):

Make the plus a very tiny div with `position:relative`. Inside that div, not visible, create your popup with `position:absolute` instead of fixed and use negative margin to position the popup above the plus

Something like this (just a quick example, but the popup scrolls with the plus button)

http://jsfiddle.net/e6xLmp97/2/